# Affiliate Links Management Addon?

Tags: add-on, redirects, links, affiliate

I want to manage all my affiliate links in one place, e.g.:

mydomain.com/link1 -> redirects to aff. link 1
mydomain.com/link2 -> redirects to aff. link 2

Is there any addon that allows the management of affiliate links like this?

Answer (score 3):

I know there is [Detour Pro](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/detour-pro) which is for doing redirects.

Since we are on the topic of affiliate and for future reference there are these add-ons which are for setting up your own affiliate links for your users FWIW:

- [Affiliator](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/affiliator)
- [Affiliate Plus](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/affiliate-plus)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I knew about detour but I was hoping there was something out there more aimed at affiliate link management. Something that allowed for adding notes and the tracking of clicks on the links for example.

Comment: I'm not aware of something though, that doesn't mean it doesn't exist. You could opt for using something like bitly which does tracking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Detour Pro](http://cityzen.com/addons/detour_pro)

This is being used for 301 redirection and works very well.